# Avoid updating entities with JPA based on timestamp column

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

let's consider two JPA entities A and B :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_a", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_a", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<>();
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME")
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;
    //getters + setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_b", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_b", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "SOMETHING")
    private String something;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private A a;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME")
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;
    //getters + setters
}
```

then consider RestController (springboot context) that have one GET method used for retrieving detail of entity A :

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ADTO> getA(@PathVariable(name = "id", required = true) Long id) {
        return aRepository.findById(id)
                .map(a -> new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.mapToDomain(a), HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

method POST used for creating records of A:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ADTO> addA(@RequestBody @Valid ADTO aDTO) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.mapToDomain(a.save(mapper.mapToEntity(ADTO))), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

and PUT method for updating :

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<ADTO> updateA(@RequestBody @Valid ADTO aDTO) {
        A a = aRepository.findById(aDTO.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        ADTO aDTOfound = mapper.mapToDomain(a);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(aDTO, aDTOfound);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.mapToDomain(aRepository.save(mapper.mapToEntity(aDTOfound), HttpStatus.OK)));
```

}

then let's say that, createdTime attribute is updated everytime the entity is persisted (including created - updating createdTime attribute is done under the hood ...).

Then let's consider scenario, where two users at the same time are retrieving detail of the same entity A (id 1). If user X update the detail from the retrieved content via PUT method, is there any way how to avoid user Y to update the same entity with old content (notice that the createdTime attribute is updated on record with id 1) ? I know that one possible solution, is to make sure that the retrieved createdTime and one from aDTO in update method is the same, but is there any "more" standard solution for this problem ? For example, how to avoid updating entity A (if it was updated previously with USER 1) but let update the childs in Bset which ones for example were not updated by user 1 ...

Comment: As a side note, it would make more sense to map the incoming DTO onto the entity, rather than map the entity to DTO back and forth

Answer (score 1):

This is typical problem statement of **Optimistic Locking**

> Optimistic locking is a mechanism that prevents an application from
> being affected by the "lost update" phenomenon in a concurrent
> environment while allowing some high degree of concurrency at the same
> time.

I will solve this problem using [@Version](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Version), add @Version field in your entity like below

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "roll_number")
    private String rollNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;
    
}
```

In above case When we create an entity for the first time default version value will be zero

On update, the field annotated with `@Version` will be incremented and subsequent update will same version will fail with `OptimisticLockException`

The @Version annotation in hibernate is used for Optimistic locking while performing update operation. For more details you can visit https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/

Comment: is there any way how to not roll-back entire transaction when OptimisticLockException occurs ? For example, let's say that user-1 updated child entity B-1 of A through A (A remain the same). Then user-2 try to update child entity B-2 of the same parent entity A as previous user. Now, the B-2 wont be updated due to OptimisticLockException caused by different version of B-1. I have only one put method - which is used to update A and  Bs in the same time. So what i want to achieve is to update childs with correct version and skip the ones with incorrect version through the one update method...

Comment: You would need to update each child in a separate transaction. Just ask yourself if it really make sense to make a partial update. This may leave your DB in an inconsistent state